# Disable category filter from head

Tags: category, layout, xml, filter

I want to delete this dropdown list `All category`:

[image]

I saw a lot of answers how to disable category dropdown via `xml`, but not of them helped me. I will be grateful if someone will explain me how to use `unsetChild`-method or something like this. This is original code:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I tried this one, but still no changes:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: post your phtml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Template path hints from backend find the path to your file `form.mini.phtml`usually it will be placed under `app\design\frontend\yourpackage\yourtheme\template\catalogsearch\form.mini.phtml`then delete the drop down list coding carefully.(If you not sure about coding create a backup copy of `form.mini.phtml` then try your tests)

If you simply want to hide dropdown listshowing on frontend only,use css `display:none` under specific `.class` on your respective stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extension, and you need to disable the extension. Try path hints and see the name, and then search in admin panel for that name and disable it.